# Make green tab appear on hover div with pure css

Tags: html, css

I have the following **HTML**

```
<table style="position:relative; left: 10px; top:5px;">
            <tr id="all_extended">
                <td id="pucenas">
                    <img id="cenas"></img>
                </td>
                <td id="slide">
                    <div id="slider">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

and **CSS**

```
#slide{
  height:100%;
  border: none;
  padding-left:20px;
  display:none;
}

#slider{
  border: none;
  padding-left:30px;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;

  transition: width 10s linear 2s;
  /* safari is webkit */
  -webkit-transition:width 1s linear 2s;
    transition: opacity 10s linear 2s;
  /* safari is webkit */
  -webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear 2s;
}

#cenas{
    width:99%;
    height:100%;
    border: solid black 1px;
    position:relative;
    left: 0%;
}

#pucenas{
  font-size: 0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#all_extended:hover #slide{
    width: 200px;
    display:inline;
}
```

What I really want is to make a green thing appear (the #slide and #slider) on hover on #all_extended. I've tried it many times but just can't get it to work (I had it on jquery). Here is a sketch about what I really want http://awwapp.com/s/99/5e/21.png. Any ideas on this one? Thank you very much!

Comment: so you hover on one of the black boxes (as in the image you provided), and then the green box next to it should appear?

Comment: yet no idea on this one guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hover on the box with the black border and display the green box, then you can do so like this:

```
#pucenas:hover + #slide {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/ErUxuvuK/1/edit).

Comment: To clarify why it works: the `+` is the [adjacent sibling](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/) selector; it selects "#slide" only if it is the next sibling after "#pucenas:hover", meaning the style only applies when hovering over its sibling.  One limitation of using sibling is that the green slider will disappear if you switch to hovering over it; using a child selector (`#all_extended > #slide`) would be a little smoother.

Comment: @davidpauljunior what I really wanted was for it to be animated... it should open and close with ease just like described in the picture I provided...

Comment: The picture really didn't show that.  Is there a reason you're using tables? It looks to me like it should be a list, and this would all be much simpler without tables.